# JQuery 'thinks' that I want to AJAX another domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iis

I just can't understand why my AJAX doesn't work. Every AJAX requests are working on my site except that one. It 'thinks' that I want to AJAX an other domain as my error code says.

Error code:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.example.com/. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://subdomain.example.com' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

I am working on a subdomain and the page I want to AJAX is on this same subdomain. For example, I want to AJAX `subdomain.example.com/get-this` from `subdomain.example.com/from-here`, my `subdomain.example.com/scripts/someting.js`.

My JS code:

```
function ButtonClick() {
    var amount;
    $(document).on('immediately', '#amount', function () {
        amount = $(this).val();
    });
    $("#amount").trigger('immediately');

    $.ajax("get-this.cshtml",
    {
        data: { operation: "add", username: $("#uname").val(), productName: $("#show-box > div > i").first().text(), amount: amount },
        success: function (response) {
            if(response == "True")
            {
                alert();
            }
            else
            {
                alert("false");
            }
        },
        error: function (request) {
            alert(amount);
            $("#error-div").text("Connection error, please try again.");
            $("#error-div").fadeIn("fast");
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#error-div").fadeOut("fast");
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
    setTimeout(Close , 1000); }
```

I don't know what is wrong, every value in the `data`section is valid (I checked) and there is no problem with the asyncrony. Please someone explain me what is happening.

Comment: That error coming because you are sending ajax request to another domain

Comment: on web.config you can use `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />` inside  `<customHeaders>`

Comment: Have you tried setting a complete URL?

Comment: what datatype you are using for response?

Comment: I work in the same domain and the subdomain.

I also tried write complete URL and got a link like this: `subdomain.example.com/subdomain.example.com/get-this`

Furthermore, in my other I use `Response.Wrtie(true)`, handle response as a string and IT WORKS well... I don't really know what's the prob.

Comment: Making ajax request to *.cshtml page ??

Answer (score 0):

change the response to data then u will get success result

```
    success: function (data) {
        if(data == "True")
        {
            alert();
        }
        else
        {
            alert("false");
        }
```

Comment: Nothing happened.

Comment: var ausername =$("#uname").val();
  var aproductName = $("#show-box > div > i").first().text();
  $.ajax({
    url:'sample.php' ,
      type: 'POST',
        data: { operation: "add", username: ausername, productName: aproductName, amount: amount },
        success: function (data) {
        alert(data);//what it's coming 'true' or anything else ok
            if(data == "True")
            {
                alert();
            }
            else
            {
                alert("false");
            }  try this dude